# Flutter using Slider to update another page

Tags: flutter

I am working on a location based app and in the settings page I have an option the allows users to change their location radius using the slider package. Such that when the slider is moved,more or less content gets shown in the home screen.

Am encountering the following problems

1.When the slider is moved, the changes dont reflect on the home page, I know this since ive inserted a text widget in the home screen to display  the slider value.

2.On the settings page where the slider is, whenever I slide it, it updates but when I navigate to another screen then back to the settings screen, the slider resets to the minimum value.
How can I solve the above problems?

**Here is my slider code on the settings page**

```
Slider(
            value: radius,
            onChanged: (newRadius) async{
              setState(() {
                tasks = newRadius.toDouble();
                String step2 = radius.toStringAsFixed(2);
                twodecimalradius = double.parse(step2); //converting the slider value to 2 decimal places

              });
              print(twodecimalradius);
              await Home(twodecimalradius:twodecimalradius); //passing the slider value to homepage
              await Home.staticGlobalKey.currentState.getposts();//a function in the homepage that gets called whenever the slider value is changed
            },

            min: 10.0,
            max: 500.0,
            //activeColor: Colors.red[400],
          )
```

**And in my homepage this is the code that is supposed to display the slider value in a text widget**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  
  var twodecimalradius;

  static final GlobalKey<_HomeState> staticGlobalKey =
  new GlobalKey<_HomeState>();

  Home({
    
    this.twodecimalradius,

  }): super(key: Home.staticGlobalKey);


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body:Text(widget.twodecimalradius))
}
```

Comment: What kind of state management are you using?

Comment: Check my link for the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71997873/4308940

Answer (score 0):

In your `Slider`, you are not passing the slider value to `HomePage`. Instead, you are creating a new unrelated instance of `HomePage`:

```
Slider(
  value: radius,
  onChanged: (newRadius) async{
    setState(() {
      ...
      await Home(twodecimalradius:twodecimalradius);
      ...
)
```

Instead, you should use some kind of State Management.

Here is a solution using [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) package:

[image]

### Full source code for easy copy-paste:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final radius = useProvider(radiusProvider).state;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyApp'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsPage()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Current radius: $radius'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final radius = useProvider(radiusProvider).state;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MyApp')),
      body: Slider(
        value: radius,
        onChanged: (newRadius) => context.read(radiusProvider).state =
            (100 * newRadius.toDouble()).roundToDouble() / 100,
        min: 10.0,
        max: 500.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

final radiusProvider = StateProvider<double>((ref) => 25.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few questions, in the part where class SettingsPage extends HookWidget am using a stateful widget in my settings page, how do I add tthe hookwidget to it?

Comment: If you use Riverpod with Flutter Hooks, you probably don't need a `StatefulWidget`. If you prefer to use a `StatefulWidget` instead of a `HookWidget`, please refer to this sample: https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/counter/lib/main.dart This sample is for a `StatelessWidget` but you can apply the same to a `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: I think I need a stateful widget because am using init state and setstate in these pages. Unless there is another way to achieve this without stateful widget

Comment: You can use `final state = useState('123456');` (https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useState.html). Flutter Hooks provides a bunch of predefined hooks: useTextEditingController, useScrollController, useFocusNode, useAnimationController, etc. (https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks#existing-hooks)